# Чи існуїть офіційна абетка Брайля

Tags: абетка

Натрапив на [таке](https://web.archive.org/web/20120908083505/http://void.net.ua/braille/) через вікіпедію.

Однак там дві проблеми.

1. Там завбачьїво підписано: *Шрифт згенеровано сценарієм braille-uk.pl (стиснено ZIP). Ні сценарій, ні ця сторінка не є офіційними джерелами для відтворення та опису шрифту Брайля для українського алфавіту.*
2. І так воно і є: відсутня буква *ґ*, а *з* повторюїть ся двічі — судячи з опису унікода, друга маїть бути *и*, котра якраз теж відсутня.

Спроба [пошукати](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8F+site%3A*.gov.ua) наприклад через *gov.ua* не дуже вдала, бо там переважно про: новини, про термінолоґію (*абетка* чи *шріфт* Брайля) і про день цеї абетки — четвертого сїчня; але при цему жодної самої абетки. Можу лише зазначити, шчо натрапив на цїкаву статтю [*Порівняльний аналіз давніх рельєфно-крапкових абеток у брайлівських стародруках, як передумова видання сучасних доступних підручників для закладів вищої освіти України*](https://enpuir.npu.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/35484/Serputko%20H.pdf?sequence=1) від Ганни Серпутько.

Comment: На сайті dls.gov.ua є інструкція з маркування лікарських засобів шрифтом Брайля, де використовується https://www.dls.gov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-1-%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8F-21.05.2019.pdf Але не дуже зрозуміло, що саме є джерелом цього документа.

Comment: В роз'яснювальному листі (https://www.dls.gov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/4047-001.1-002.0-17-19-1.pdf) міститься посилання на Українське товариство сліпих, але на їхньому сайті (http://cputos.org.ua/) відповідний документ гуглопошук не знаходить.